# Android SwipeRefreshLayout refresh listview with blinks

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a listview wrapped in a SwipeRefreshLayout. The listview renders very smoothly in anytime I update it with new data. But whenever I pull down SwipeRefreshLayout to get new messages,the listview gives me a blink effect which is negative in terms of user experience. I found nothing useful to fix this issue after searching a lot on the internet.Can any one teach me how to resolve this problem.

Below is part of my code:

```
    public void fetchMoreMsgs(){
    sizeOfChatLV=chatLVArray.size();
    if(lvPos==0){
        toast = Toast.makeText(ma,"No more messages",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }else {
        if(lvPos-fetchStep>=0){
            arrayList = chatLVArray.subList(lvPos-fetchStep, lvPos);
            msgsList.addAll(0, arrayList);
            chatLVArrayAdapter = new ChatLVArrayAdapter(ma, msgsList);
            ma.chatListViewIMP2P.setAdapter(chatLVArrayAdapter);
            ma.chatListViewIMP2P.setSelection(fetchStep);
            lvPos-=fetchStep;
        }else {
            arrayList = chatLVArray.subList(0, lvPos);
            msgsList.addAll(0, arrayList);
            chatLVArrayAdapter = new ChatLVArrayAdapter(ma, msgsList);
            ma.chatListViewIMP2P.setAdapter(chatLVArrayAdapter);
            ma.chatListViewIMP2P.setSelection(lvPos);
            lvPos=0;
        }
    }
}
```

The fetchMoreMsgs method is called when I pull down the listview(wrapped in a SwipeRefreshLayout).Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call `setAdapter`, it completely destroys every view in the `ListView` and then creates it anew. This is what causes your blinking effect.

Instead, your `chatLVArrayAdapter` should have a way to updating the underlying list and then you should call your adapter's [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) to tell `ListView` the data has changed.

Comment: I will try notifyDataSetChanged() later.It does look more efficient. But setAdapter never produces blinking effect in other situations as long as no involvement of SwipeRefreshLayout. Maybe this is caused by the implementation of my ArrayAdapter which does not use ViewHolder to resue convertview(My list takes two types of row. I dont know how to put them in ViewHolder). But Its still hard to explain why the listview does not blink in other cases.

Comment: I just came up an ugly solution which looks like this: 
                public void onRefresh() {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    p2PTalkView.fetchMoreMsgs();
                                    p2pSwipeRFL.setRefreshing(false);
                                }});
                        }}).start();
                }

Comment: The blinking is gone but I don't know why

Comment: Just add a `setList` method on your adapter. There's no reason to hack around the correct way of doing it

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() works great. Thank you so much. I feel more confident about using listview now.